# send (post) data with image to RestFull API using Flutter

Tags: api, http, flutter, post

how can i send data with image url to RestFull API in flutter, this is my code, but it is not work, the problem just because the image, and all data sent successfully:

```
 String imgUrl;

  insertService() async {
    var res = await http.post(
        "http://192.168.43.106:3000/service",
        headers: {},
        body: {
          "name" : namec.text,
          "file" : imgUrl,
          "desc" : descc.text,
          "price" : pricec.text,
          "cat" : widget.cid
        }
    );

    final data = json.decode(res.body);

    if(data['message'] != null && data['message'] == 'success'){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Services(cid: widget.cid,)));
    }else{
      print("there is a problem in post request....");
    }
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final img = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: ()async{
          var imageIns =  await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
          setState(() {
            image = File(imageIns.path);
            imgUrl = imageIns.path;
          });
```

and with postman, everything work good even with image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact type of `imageIns.path` ? If its a object you probably need to encode it as json.